# process hangs after redirecting stderr using exec

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, exec, stderr

I want to redirect stdout and stderr to 2 pipes one for each

to create the pipes I used:

```
    mkfifo -m 0666 /var/run/log_stdout.pipe
    mkfifo -m 0666 /var/run/log_stderr.pipe
```

and it works fine, but when I try to redirect process hangs

```
   exec 2>/var/run/log_stderr.pipe
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are doing this on the command line, then you will now notice that the interactive shell's prompt is redirected to your `log_stderr.pipe` FIFO.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the *stderr* pipe for reading. Until this is done the open for writing will block

Comment: How do you open a stderr pipe?

Comment: @GautamSomani same as any other: you read from it. (Note that the question creates a pipe for _stderr_, and it's this that needs to be read.)